# Axioms for the generalized cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, group-cohomology

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology#Axioms_and_generalized_cohomology_theories) I would like to understand in the homotopy axiom
what is the **induced** homomorphism on (co)homology?
What it means and how is the induced homomorphism defined?

Comment: It depends on the theory. That’s like asking how is the binary operation defined in group theory.

Comment: But I know what is a group but in contrast I do not know what is the induced homomorphism. Could you help me to understand it?

Comment: My point was that it is an abstraction.  If you know examples of cohomology theories then you know how the induced maps arise.  If you don’t then you shouldn’t yet study the generalization.

Comment: I believe that the induced thing is something very easy to describe and tell, but I cannot read it uniquely from the definition of the generalized cohomology on that wikipedia page.

Comment: I’ll let someone else take over.

Comment: No, you really are not going to hear something uniformly for all cohomology theories at once, unless you are satisfied with "A cohomology theory is representable by homotopy classes of maps to a spectrum $Z$, and the induced map of $f: X \to Y$ is precomposotion $[Y, Z] \to [X, Z]$." In general the definition of eg the induced maps in K-theory look different than the induced maps on singular cohomology.

Comment: @Randall anyway, your comments were correct.